# How to specify address and telephone number in resume in a vertical manner?

Tags: sectioning, vertical-alignment

Hi i am making my resume. I want to write some more details such as residential address, Skype address, tel phone number in a vertical manner. How do i do it? Here is my code.

```
\namesection{}{name}{ \urlstyle{same}
\href{mailto:badus@gmail.com}{badus@gmail.com}}
```

Now how do I add more details in a vertical manner and also in two columns side by side?

Comment: Which documentclass do you use?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer \documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's two ways of doing it (should work with any class), one with `flushleft` and `flushright`, and the other with the `tabularx` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
% flushright/flushleft method
\begin{flushright}
  {\Huge Foo Bar} \\
  {\Large Curriculum Vitae} \\[1em]
  +1123581321 \\
  100 Quux Lane, Bazland
\end{flushright}
\vspace{-1.95cm} % Big downside is the need for this manual re-spacing
\begin{flushleft}
  Lot's of other \\
  Random detail
\end{flushleft}

\vspace{2cm}

% tabularx method, better IMHO. There are three columns, the middle X column is
% the filler, and the left and right are for content.
\noindent \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l X r}
  & & {\Huge Foo Bar} \\
  & & {\Large Curriculum Vitae} \\[1em]
  Lot's of other & & +1123581321 \\
  Random detail & & 100 Quux Lane, Bazland
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]